# From SQLoader to External Tables [Oracle]

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, external-tables

At the moment I have some flat files, that are loaded in DB with SQLoader, but I would like to replace SQLoader scripts with external tables, but I am having problems with "translating" SQLoader to external tables.

So, for example I have a flat file, something like this:

```
~#~col1>|col2>|col3...
```

And I have a SQloader .ctl file, which looks something like this:

```
LOAD DATA                                                                       
APPEND
CONTINUEIF NEXT PRESERVE (1:3) <> '~#~'
INTO TABLE my_tab
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ">|"  TRAILING NULLCOLS          
(                                                                               
  col1                 "LTRIM(Trim(:col1),'~#~')",
  col2                 "TRIM(:col2)",                                          
  col3                 "TRIM(:col3)",
  col4                  CONSTANT #$TASKID$#,
  col5                  CONSTANT #$SESSION$#,
  col6                  RECNUM,
  col7                  SEQUENCE(MAX)
)
```

At the moment I have tried a lot of things -

```
create table my_tab(
   col1    varchar2(100) 
  ,col2    number(38)         
  ,col3    number(38)
  ,... 
)
organization external(
  type oracle_loader
    default directory my_dir
    access parameters(
      records delimited by newline
      fields terminated by '>|' 
      missing field values are null
      reject rows with all null fields
    )
    location('my_file.txt')
 );
```

So I have a following question:

How do I call TRIM function, when defining external table? (is it even   possible?) Or the only way is to create another view/table for data staging, and do all data transformations and then insert data into target table?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your records will always start with `~#~` you can consume that with a couple of dummy columns that don't map to the table definition:

```
create table my_tab(
   col1    varchar2(100) 
  ,col2    number(38)         
  ,col3    number(38)
)
organization external(
  type oracle_loader
    default directory my_dir
    access parameters(
      records delimited by newline
      fields terminated by '>|' 
      missing field values are null
      reject rows with all null fields
      (
        colx char(1) terminated by "~",
        coly char(1) terminated by "~",
        col1,
        col2,
        col3
      )
    )
    location('my_file.txt')
 );
```

The default behaviour without [trim clause specified](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1411) is `LDRTRIM`, which behaves the same as SQL*Loader's `TRIM`. You can also set that to `NOTRIM` as specify the whitespace trimming for each column.

---

If you want to discard your EOF marker records but load everything else you can use the [`LOAD WHEN` option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1393), optionally with [`NODISCARDFILE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1395) if you don't want to keep a record of them:

```
...
organization external(
  type oracle_loader
    default directory d42
    access parameters(
      records delimited by newline
      load when (1:15) != "###~~~EOF~~~###"
      nodiscardfile
      fields terminated by '>|' 
...
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, that worked like a charm! But I have two more questions: 

1) Is there a way to stop loading when specific value in text file has been reached (flat file has EOF marker which looks like this - ###~~~EOF~~~###). Currently markers are being logged in .bad file as bad records, number of EOF markers is inconsistent (can be one, can be four); 

2)Is there a way to dynamically set location of flat file, cause everyday flat file has different name? File mask is like <my_file*.txt>

Comment: @UldisBajārs - not sure if you mean discard everything after the first EOF marker, or just skip those 1-4 records? Either way you can ask that as a new question, with details and examples. You can change the file name with `alter table my_tab location('<name>')`, and if the name contains the date could do that dynamically based on sysdate say. Might be easier to rename/link the daily file to a fixed name in your directory though.

Comment: Didn't knew about `alter table my_tab location('<name>')`, that will work, thank you! Regarding that EOF marker, my teamlead said that for now, as a temporary solution, a basic shell script to remove those markers will suffice. Thanks again!

Comment: @UldisBajārs - OK, if you're just discarding them, I've added how to do that as part of the table definition. Should be a new question really but not sure it's worth it at this point.